# How to cut a rectangle out of a cylinder?

Tags: modeling

Which is the best way to model this circle?
How to cut out a rectangle out of a cylinder?
I have issues with the subdivision modif.
Maybe boolean?

[image]

Comment: No need for all caps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your shape is a little bit more complicate than just rectangles on cylinder, but if I had to do the basic shape of rectangles on cylinder, as it is a pattern repeated around a circle, I would do it with a *Simple Deform* modifier / *Bend* mode:

- First create your pattern with a plane that you rotate, subdivide, extrude, as it is symmetrical on the X, Y and Z axis you can use a *Mirror* modifier with the *Clipping* option activated.

[image]

- Repeat the pattern with an *Array* modifier. Enable the *Merge* and *First Last* options.

[image]

- Apply the rotation of your object (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) to make sure it is. Give your object a *Simple Deform* modifier, choose the *Bend* mode and a *Deform Angle* of 360°.

[image]

- Now as you are going to add a *Subdivision Surface* it's hard to keep a rectangle without completely messing the mesh. Here is the topology I would personally use: Create a bevel on the 90° rectangle angle, join some vertices, dissolve some edges, add some edge loops to sharp the angles, as below.

[image]

You can continue to work on your basic shape so that it looks more like the real one.

Comment: I've tried it the first time and it works, Thank you.. BUT, i've tried it again and than i got an ugly oval circle... What can be the problem? During "apply roation" or extruding? Pls can you help me again?

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: I got it :). I've apply not only the Rotation but also Scale. Thank you very much!